# Would a japanese person recognize this icon (fa-language) to represent translation or language change?

Tags: meaning, kanji

[image]

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/language

[image: fa-language]

https://fontawesome.com/icons/language?style=solid

(Somewhat unrelated but what are those kanjis? I guess the lower one is 文? Is the upper one just a variation of the same kanji or is it a different one? -*Sorry, I'm illiterate when it comes to kanji.*)

I assume that to an English reader the kanji here doesn't matter much and I think any non-english symbol would pass (at least in the right context), but for a Japanese reader? Are those kanji a Chinese thing only perhaps or recognized in all kanji-using countries?

And most importantly: Would it be weird to use those on a Japanese website?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the icon is supposed to mean "change language", it suggests that its designer cannot distinguish between languages and scripts. This I think makes it totally unfit for purpose.

Comment: @BrianChandler That's quite the statement when you have no idea of the context. For example, wikipedia uses a very similar icon for changing language on their mobile site. In fact, I wouldn't have bothered with the question if I had spotted that earlier on.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/wikimedia/WikiFont/issues/32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower one is indeed 文, a kanji meaning *sentence* or *text*. The icon makes perfect sense to Japanese audience, too. The upper one is not a kanji I know, but it looks like a [Korean consonant ㅊ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0GuM4LBBsVQ) (it probably does not have its own meaning). If you only target at Japanese audience, I recommend you use the lower one.